# Convert one item in a key value dict to an int

Tags: python-3.x

The dict is a json output of key values, they are stored as a string key and string value. I want one value identified by key creation_date. Example of a output by printing based of the key creation_date.

Code:

```
print({scan["creation_date"]})
```

Output:

```
{creation_date: 1692376305}
```

Tried:

```
creation_date_int = int({scan["creation_date"]})
```

Got:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'
```

Tried:

```
scan[creation_date] = int(scan[creation_date])
```

Got:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'local'
```

Both:

```
scan[creation_date] = float(scan[creation_date])  & scan[creation_date] = int(float(scan[creation_date]))
```

Got:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'local'
```

Just want to convert the value 1692376305 to an int or float by the key creation_date

Answer (score 0):

Got it with the following code

```
n = int(list(scan.values())[4])
print(n)
print("\n")
```

which outputs `1659970453`.

Then, was able to convert to a more readable time in this manner

```
n = int(list(scan.values())[4])
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(n)
print(dt)
```

which outputs `2022-08-08 10:54:13`.